# AWS Athena is giving multiple "Connection pool is full, discarding connection" warnings while firing queries from a pyathena package

Tags: amazon-athena, connection-pooling, pyathena

When firing athena queries from a locally built pyathena package, I am getting "Connection pool is Full" - Warnings. After some time the query hit is successful. How can I increase the connection pool limit from AWS Athena end?

The pyathena package simply makes connection to AWS Athena and does not involve any connection pool queue to modify according to requirements.

Dummy query : "select * from bucketname.tablename where timestampcol >= {} and timestampcol < {}"